# Accessing a method before instantiating

Tags: c++, class, instantiation

I want to access class InternalNode's getSurplus() method.

I have getSurplus() defined in a "InternalNode.h" file.

"..." means other code.

How do I refer to the method getSurplus from the InternalNode class?

```
//InternalNode.h
{
class InternalNode:public BTreeNode

{
 ...

 void remove(int a);
 int getSurplus() const;
 ...
 }

}



int InternalNode::getSurplus() const
{
 return (count - (internalSize + 1) / 2);
}

//
BTreeNode* InternalNode::remove(int value)
{
...

if (children[i]->getSurplus() >= 0) return SURPLUS; //Not correct syntax

...
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `children`?

Comment: It's a pointer to an array of `BtreeNode*` types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `children` is an array of `BtreeNode*` objects, and `InternalNode` is derived from `BtreeNode`, then provided that the pointer returned from `children[i]` is in-fact a pointer to a `InternalNode` object (and not some other derived object of `BtreeNode`), you have to explicitly cast the pointer back to a type `InternalNode*`.  This could be done like so:

```
if (static_cast<InternalNode*>(children[i])->getSurplus() >= 0)
```

If you are **not sure** that each `BtreeNode*` is pointing to an `InternalNode` object (i.e., it could be pointing to some other derived type), then you're going to have to use a `dynamic_cast<InternalNode*>(children[i])`, and check to make sure the operation returns a valid pointer, and not `NULL`.

So if you're absolutely sure about the types in your array, then you can use `static_cast<>()` in this situation (i.e., right now `BtreeNode` is the only base-class of `InternalNode`, it is not a virtual base class, etc.) ... otherwise if you want to be safe at the cost of some run-time overhead, use `dynamic_cast<>()` and check for a `NULL` pointer return value from the cast operation.

Comment: No, children[i] returns a ptr to BTreeNode.                         children = new BTreeNode* [size];

Comment: You are assuming all pointers in `children` are instances of `InternalNode` which may not be correct. If OP really wants to do this, I feel its better to use `dynamic_cast` with a NULL check.

Comment: I was adding that as you typed that comment :)

Comment: thanks that worked. but after children = new BTreeNode* [size]; can I do: dynamic_cast<InternalNode*>(children)? So I Don't have to do this everytime on every InternalNode method?

Comment: Unfortunately you have to perform this every time you access a pointer from `children` and want to treat that pointer as-if it pointed to a derived object. The only other alternative would be to declare `getSurplus` as a pure `virtual` method of `BtreeNode`.  This would force every derived object of `BtreeNode` to define `getSurplus()` at the cost of not being able to construct a `BtreeNode` instance directly.  But abstract base classes are often used in situations like this when you want to define a common interface among derived objects.